# ERROR 6777001: Init failed - Pro blem setting up in-app billing: IabResult: Billing service failed to initialize. (response: 6:Error)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Do you have any idea how to fix it? I'm using `Apache Cordova` and [this plugin](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase). Plugin seems to be set up correctly, but communication with the store doesn't work.

> Logs can be seen here:
>
> ```
> 09-30 20:18:08.206 5602-5602/com.gamelegance.game I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(412)] "refresh", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (412)
> 09-30 20:18:08.207 5602-5602/com.gamelegance.game I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(460)] "[store.js] DEBUG: store.trigger -> triggering action refreshed", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cc.fovea.cordova.purchase/www/store-android.js (460)
> 09-30 20:18:08.207 5602-5602/com.gamelegance.game I/chromium﹕[INFO:CONSOLE(460)] "[store.js] DEBUG: queries !! 'refreshed'" source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cc.fovea.cordova.purchase/www/store-android.js (460)
> 09-30 20:18:08.207 5602-5602/com.gamelegance.game I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(735)] "InAppBilling[js]: setup ok", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cc.fovea.cordova.purchase/www/store-android.js (735)
>  --------- beginning of system
>
> 09-30 20:18:54.325 5602-5602/com.gamelegance.game I/chromium﹕[INFO:CONSOLE(412)] "ERROR 6777001: Init failed - Problem setting up in-app billing: IabResult: Billing service failed to initialize. (response: 6:Error)", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (412)
> ```

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct billing key when setting it up?

Comment: Yes, I'm using correct key.

Comment: Does this error happen when you try to make a purchase? Or when you are doing store setup?